# Chromecast debugger unavailable

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I'm trying to develop a new application for Chromecast device. 
However I can't access to Chromecast Debugger by the URL http://[CHROMECAST-IP]:9222 after I've launched my receiver app in Chrome (OS X 10.10.4 / version 45.0.2454.15 dev (64-bit), but it the same with all version).

I've already rebooted and made factory reset my Chromecast few times. My device is also well registered on Google Cast SDK Developer Console and I'm very sure with the device number (I checked 10 times). My app is also registered with an App Id and I'm on the same WiFi network of Chromecast when I cast with my Chrome sender.

Finally, my firmware version is 32904.

Someone can help me to resolve this problem ? If you need other information, ask me.

Comment: When you go to the debugging page, what do you see? Is it just a blank page?

Comment: Sorry I forget the main thing, Chrome send the error : 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. It seems the port 9222 is closed but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please contact our [support](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) for this issue; they can help you debug your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where I can I find the Developper ID number please ?

Comment: Just enter your email address there (the one associated with your developer account); that form is slightly outdated and will be updated to make that clear soon.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a Chromecast device you need to register the app and the Google Cast device and then go to `chrome://inspect`.

Detailed instructions are here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging